# Values of $b(h_a)-a(h_b)$ with $a,b$ being roots in root system of a Lie algebra

Tags: lie-algebras, root-systems, semisimple-lie-algebras, weyl-group

Let $a,b$ be roots in a root system of a finite dimensional complex semisimple Lie algebra. I want to determine the possible values of $b(h_a)-a(h_b)$.

The difference equals zero when $a=b$ (clearly) or $a=-b$ (that is $a+b=0$)  since $b(h_a)-a(h_b)=b[e_a,e_b]-a[e_b,e_a]=(b+a)[e_a,e_b]=0$ by how the Cartan Weyl basis acts under the Lie bracket.

I'm having trouble finding other cases. I know that $h_a=\frac{2}{\langle a,a\rangle}t_a$ where $t_a$ is the image under the map $\mathfrak{h}^*\rightarrow \mathfrak{h}$ with $\mathfrak{h}$ being a fixed Cartan subalgebra. However this doesn't get me much further.

Comment: Note that the thing you ask for in standard notation is $\check{\alpha}(\beta) - \check{\beta}(\alpha)$, and $\check{\alpha}(\beta)$ is often abbreviated as $n_{\beta, \alpha}$ or $n(\alpha, \beta)$ or something. Every good text on root systems lists all the finitely many possibilities for the relation between two roots, which is completely determined by $n(\alpha, \beta)$ and $n(\beta, \alpha)$, which are $\in \lbrace 0, \pm1, \pm 2, \pm 3 \rbrace$. The non-trivial examples are obviously in the root systems $B_n, C_n, F_4$ and $G_2$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. So if we consider the table on page 8 in http://personalpages.to.infn.it/~billo/didatt/gruppi/root.pdf, then $\check{\alpha}(\beta)$ corresponds to $\langle \beta,\alpha\rangle$ and $\check{\beta}(\alpha)$ corresponds to $\langle \alpha,\beta\rangle$?

Comment: I think so, yes. That "hook" notation is also quite common but I try to avoid it because it looks symmetric, where the whole point of your question is that in general it's not.